# image upload with security related issue

Tags: node.js, security, file-upload, base64

I have a service where users can upload images (in the form of base64-encoded string) to the server and the server will convert the string to an image file and upload it to the AWS.

What if the base64-encoded string is a malware or virus in disguise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a valid concern.  One way to deal with this is to run an up-to-date malware detection on the decoded file before making it public.  If it fails, don't allow it to be seen by anyone.  Check out [clamav](http://www.clamav.net/index.html) for one such option.

Comment: so in my case I am running a node.js server on ubuntu 14.04 instance so I'd expect to run all my upload services through clamav before storing / processing the files. is that what you mean?

Comment: @Shih-MinLee > it isn't really realted to the technology you're using but yes indeed he means you need to run a sanity check on it. You actually should sanitize any user input into your system.

Comment: I searched a bit and found there's an npm module called `clamscan` that does maybe what you said.  Currently I upload all my files to `/public` folder and do I have to do something about the permissions this way?

Comment: The specifics of how you invoke the scanner will depend on your specific workflow, hosting service, OS, and execution platform.  You might consider a separate question that lays all that out.

Comment: guess I should go with ClamAV and clamscan. clamscan developers say they will support real time scan after version 0.9 so I guess I'll just scan every base64 encoded string before I convert them into files then..

Comment: To be clear: don't scan the Base64 string -- decode into a quarantine area, scan the binary and only once declared "safe" then move into the final staging area (otherwise delete).  Scanners don't normally decode B64 before scanning.  This will not put your server at risk unless you attempt to execute the binary before scanning it.